# unable to fetch elements from ie using selenium webdriver on WinServer 2012

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, internet-explorer-10

I am using selenium 2.33 with IEDriveServer on windows server 2012 in Python.

I am unable to fetch any element using WebDriver.

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Ie()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
driver.find_element_by_name('q')
```

IE window opened successfully but fetching the element is not successful. 
I am getting error:

`unable to find element with name = q`

I tried even `find_element_by_id` with different pages.

My script is working on win7 and win8 but it is not working with ie10 on winserver2012

Comment: A few things: update to the latest version of Selenium, check the protected mode settings and see if there are any different results with 32bit/64bit IE.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in Java, but I think it should work with python as well. I got into a similar situation where findElement by xpath or id didn't work on IE9. So I tried using cssSelector and it worked great. Not sure what the syntax for python would be, but in Java it looks like the following, hope this helps
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector));`

Comment: But fetching by id is supposed to work right?
I doubt if it has something to do with ie 10 setting on windows 2012 which are related to javascript as selenium fetching elements work based on javascript. 

Correct me if i am wrong. 

Anyway i am unable to solve this problem and so i am looking for help.

Comment: I've had mixed experience with ID's, so can't really say that it will work or not. Did you try with css selector though?

Comment: I am supposed to do it using id . So i am confused why it is not working on winserver 2k12.